# JavaScript - how to prepend an element in the header tag

Tags: javascript

I am trying to prepend a stylesheet file dynamically generated into my header tag.

The problem I've got is that I need this file to be added before any other CSS files.

I tried using `insertBefore()` but that seems to remove the element I am using as an identifier for the element to be appended instead of just appending the new one above it.

Here's the code:

```
 CssFile = document.getElementById('my-css')
 Link = document.createElement('link')
 Link.href = "example.css"
 Link.type = 'text/css'
 Link.rel = 'stylesheet'
 Link.insertBefore(CssFile, Link.childNodes[0])
```

My index.html is like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/my.css" rel="stylesheet" id="my-css">
    <link href="css/vendor.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

and what I expect after the function is executed is this result:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="example.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/my.css" rel="stylesheet" id="my-css">
    <link href="css/vendor.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

but instead, this is what I get:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="example.css" rel="stylesheet">
    // Missing file here!
    <link href="css/vendor.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

I had a look at the documentation but apparently I didn't really understand how to use this.

Comment: @RajshekarReddy Fixed it. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** The way you are using the `insertBefore` is wrong. Explaining the issue.

From the Docs of **[insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)**  This is the syntax you need to use

> parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode);

You need a parent node, Then use `insertBefore` on it by passing the `newNode` and `referenceNode`.

What you have is `Link.insertBefore(CssFile, Link.childNodes[0])` .
Here you are trying to insert `CssFile` to `Link` as parent and `Link.childNodes[0]` as reference.

So when you do the above the `CssFile` element is insertedBefore `Link` and hence its removed from its original position.

---

**Solution:**

So in your HTML `head` is the parent node. You can get it by `CssFile.parentNode`

New Node is `Link`

Reference Node is `CssFile`

So Replace your `Link.insertBefore(CssFile, Link.childNodes[0])`  by

```
CssFile.parentNode.insertBefore(Link , CssFile);
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the explanation. It worked perfectly ;)

Comment: @Nick Glad to help .. happy coding !!

Answer (score 1):

The Node.insertBefore() method inserts the specified node before the reference node as a child of the current node.

here the reference node is

```
document.getElementById('my-css')
```

The node where the new node need to be added is

```
document.querySelector("head");
```

You need to make the below changes in your code.

```
 Link = document.createElement('link')
 Link.href = "example.css"
 Link.type = 'text/css'
 Link.rel = 'stylesheet'

 document.querySelector("head").insertBefore(Link, document.getElementById('my-css'));
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/MY6F4JdYPvqdYNIU7DUF?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

id is not a valid attribute to the link DOM. What I would recommend is selecting with `.querySelector('[href="css/vendor.cs"]')`

Answer (score 0):

insertBefore must be used with the parent node

```
var CssFile = document.querySelector('[href="css/vendor.css"]'); // Peter Chon is right
var Link = document.createElement('link');
Link.href = "example.css";
Link.type = 'text/css';
Link.rel = 'stylesheet';

var parent = CssFile.parentNode;
parent.insertBefore(Link, CssFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<head id="my-css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<link href="css/my.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<link href="css/vendor.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

JS

```
CssFile = document.getElementById('my-css')
Link = document.createElement('link')
Link.href = "example.css"
Link.type = 'text/css'
Link.rel = 'stylesheet'
CssFile.insertBefore(Link, CssFile.childNodes[4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs for `Node.insertBefore()`

> var insertedNode = parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode);

I think your problem is that you have the newNode and ReferenceNode the wrong way around. Also you need to reference the `parent` node.

```
CssFile = document.getElementById('my-css')
 Link = document.createElement('link')
 Link.href = "example.css"
 Link.type = 'text/css'
 Link.rel = 'stylesheet'
 CssFile.parentNode.insertBefore(Link, CssFile)
```

Comment: If you are going to down vote an answer please explain why you feel the answer is not useful.