# How do you add a heading to the chart generated by github-calendar?

Tags: javascript, html, github, charts, visualization

I am using [github-calendar](https://github.com/Bloggify/github-calendar) to show my Github contributions on my website. I would like to add a title to the chart like it is shown in [this comment](https://github.com/Bloggify/github-calendar/issues/48#issuecomment-365548128). In my case, I just want bold text saying 'Contributions in the past 365 days.'

[Screenshot of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkmju.png)

I have tried adding text inside the div, but it appears to be overwritten because I don't see it in the DOM.

```html
<!-- Prepare a container for your calendar. -->
<div class="calendar">
<p>Contributions in the past 365 Days</p>
</div>
<script>

  GitHubCalendar(
    ".calendar",
    "jsolly", {
    global_stats: false,
    responsive: true,

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to fork [`Bloggify/github-calendar`](https://github.com/Bloggify/github-calendar) and modify [`lib/index.js`](https://github.com/Bloggify/github-calendar/blob/8915857d603714069629aefd0fb85901e22a30e2/lib/index.js#L124-L130)  yourself.

For instance, [using a `insertBefore` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41247309/6309) to insert an `<h2></h2>` title before the `svg.js-calendar-graph-svg` section.